# Loading a whole mySQL table into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with 4 columns and 23 rows. I need all 92 values in the the table as PHP variables (whether that be one array, 4 arrays, 92 individual variables, or whatever).

The rows are:
ID
Category
Summary
Text

I need to build a series of select boxes where the items are grouped by the category, the options available are the summaries, and the resulting text is passed on for processing.

I've been searching, but all the examples I can find are about printing the table out, and I need to continue working with the variables.

I really appreciate any help!
Billy

Comment: Your `ID=>Column Title=>Value` doesn't match your list of columns `ID, Category, Summary, Text`. What you're asking is simple if you give us the correct set of column names.

Comment: You mean because the ID is just another column and not the top of the hierarchy?  The ID doesn't have to be the name of the array if that's a problem.  Obviously, I just need some way to identify the variable for each row, column, and value.

Comment: No, I just mean your question doesn't make total sense the way you have it. It isn't clear what you mean by Column and Value.

Answer (score 4):

Just a `SELECT * FROM table_name` will select all the columns and rows.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($results);
if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // You have $row['ID'], $row['Category'], $row['Summary'], $row['Text']
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, then perhaps I was over-thinking it.  There doesn't need to be anything in the `while` loop?  And $row will just be sequential numbering starting at zero?  
Thank you!  
Billy

Comment: Yes, the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` keeps calling all the rows one after the other until it runs out. :)

Comment: So, if I wanted to print the summary from the 4th row, it would be `echo $4['summary'];`?  
Thanks!  
Billy

Comment: If you wanted the 4th row, you'd just edit your sql query to include a limit and an offset. `$4['summary']` won't return anything because there is no `$4`

Comment: I need every row though.  To make my one page/form, I'll need to use all 92 values in the table (32 x 4) as variables.  I know how to select them all with mySQL, I just don't know how to turn them all into variables in PHP.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: OK, but how do I reference the summary in the fourth row, for instance?  I'm going to need to reference all of them individually.  
I appreciate your help @Indranil!

Comment: you'll be looking for something like this within the `while` loop:
`echo $row['Summary'];` to echo it to the browser. For each `while` loop, that particular row's `$row['ID']`, `$row['Category']`, `$row['Summary']` & `$row['Text']` will be available to you.

Comment: Yeah, see... that's the problem, I need it all available to me at the same time.  Maybe I need to explain more.  Each ID is unique.  There are 8 categories which will form 8 select boxes.  The summaries will be the actual options within the select boxes.  When a user makes all 8 selections, they click submit and 8 paragraphs will be assembled from the "text" associated with the chosen summaries.  
So, I have to have all 92 variables available at once so I can mix and match and build my form.  I'm sorry, I must be doing a horrible job at explaining this.

Comment: Ok, you can use [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) to retrieve any row at any time, or store the variables in a custom array. :) Either of this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found my answer with better search terms.  I'm still new here, so let me know if this is not a fair way to handle the situation.  I upvoted @Indranil since he or she spent so much time trying to help me.

Anyway...

```
    $content = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $content[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
```

Puts my whole entire table into one huge, multidimensional array so that I can use it throughout my code.  And it even names the first level of the array by the ID (which is the unique identifier).

Thank you to those that tried to help me!
Billy

Comment: please can you define "$result" what is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=database;charset=utf-8', 
    'username', 
    'password'
);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT ID, Category, Summary, Text FROM Table');
if ( $stmt !== false )
{
   $data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```

In the case if the SQL query has no conditions, use [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) , otherwise, you should be using [`prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) ans bind the parameters.

Oh .. and please stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions, they are in the process of being deprecated and no new code should written with them.

Comment: I'm going to have to read up on some things before I can understand your answer.  So, I'll get back to you.  I really appreciate your time and response.

Comment: @tereško everything on thins world, including me and you are in the process of being depreciated :))